# Unable to view the list of data when setting a condition

Tags: asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

I was going to display all the data from the database when the condition is true but ,it somehow return nothing even though my code doesn't have any type of errors.Here is my code

```
var data = (from a in Model
            where Model.Any(x => x.CharityInfo.CharityId == id)
            select a).ToList();
```

And this one the code for the output result

```
@foreach (var item in data)
{
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:2em   ;">
        <div class="row" id="border">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="/img/event.jpg" style="width:21em;height:auto;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventsName)</h3>
                Expected Visitor: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Target_Participant) person<br />
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed your query is in fact returning data?

Comment: @JobesK but the code didn't return any errors right ?

Comment: You say no errors but you aren't getting any output, there fore you'd probably want to confirm if the program is even returning any rows (it is falling into the foreach loop at all?) I'd check the data.rows.count and if zero write out something notating so.

Comment: I understand now because it need to do it in the controller so the model can get the thing that i want